# Cordova 3.3.x - Android CordovaLib

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

When was the cordova.jar file removed from Cordova and replaced with CordovaLib? I was previously running Cordova 3.1.0-0.1.0.

Today I have upgraded to Cordova 3.3.0 (which was quite a headache, but I've completed the upgrade) and I've noticed a difference in my Android project structure: Cordova has created my project (with what I've named it) and it has also created -CordovaLibs.

Is this right? I know iOS it does this - but not Android (as I say, usually a JAR is added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's introduced in 3.3, had me baffled too.

Cordova 3.3 release notes:
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2013/12/16/cordova-330.html

> CB-5232 Change create script to use Cordova as a Library Project
>   instead of a .jar

Comment: Thanks! Did you have problems running `cordova platform update android`? I did :( I had to restart my project in a new directory in fact because of it - a step I wished I didn't have to take.

Comment: Yeh I updated from cordova 2.7 to 3.3, and it was painful. Ended up having to create a brand new project from the command line, and once eclipse was happy to build the new project, then transferred my code & assets into there. Not ideal but got it working eventually!

Answer (score 0):

To generate file `cordova3.3.0.jar`, just follow these steps bellow:

1. Open your cmd, and go to the root folder where Cordova is installed:

   `$ cd ~/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/framework`
2. Run the following command, notice the trailing dot

   `$ android update project -p .`
3. Use ant to generate file jar. Be sure you have configure PATH for

   `$ ant jar`

Now, you can copy file cordova3.3.0.jar to libs directory and import to your project. Hope it's helpful